# max_element stl error during compilation in g++

Tags: c++, stl

This is the program, I am trying to implement a priority_queue using stl vector:
there is a compile time error which i have copy pasted at the end. Help is appreciated. There is an error in the Top() function implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

/*
APIs to be supported:
1. Top()
2. Pop()
3. Push()
DS:
vector
Algo:
*/

template<typename T>
class MyOwnPQ
{
    public:
    vector<T> vContainer;

    bool cmp_fync(T a, T b)
    {
        return a < b;
    }

    void Top() const
    {
        typename vector<T>::iterator pos; //Very important does not compile without the typename.
        pos = max_element(vContainer.begin(), vContainer.end());
        //return *pos;
    }

    void Push(const T& element)
    {
        vContainer.push_back(element);
    }

};

int main()
{
    MyOwnPQ<int> m_MyOwnPQ;
    m_MyOwnPQ.Push(1);
    m_MyOwnPQ.Push(2);
    m_MyOwnPQ.Push(3);

    m_MyOwnPQ.Top();

}
```

The error is:

```
E:\c++>g++ MyOwnPQ.cpp
MyOwnPQ.cpp: In member function 'void MyOwnPQ<T>::Top() const [with T = int]':
MyOwnPQ.cpp:49:   instantiated from here
MyOwnPQ.cpp:31: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'pos = std::max_element [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >](((const MyOwnPQ<int>*)this)
->MyOwnPQ<int>::vContainer.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](), ((const MyOwnPQ<int>*)this)->MyOwnPQ<int>::vContainer.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _
Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]())'
c:\dwimperl\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:691: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>
 > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)
```

Help is really appreciated :) .

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign to a normal iterator in a const context (since you declared that `Top` can be used with a const object). Change the iterator to be a `const_iterator`:

```
typename vector<T>::const_iterator pos;
```

Comment: Or use `auto pos = max_element(vContainer.begin(), vContainer.end());`

Comment: I am using c++ 98, I think auto is supported only in C++11 onwards. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks it compiled successfully with the const_iterator. :)

Comment: @Catalin not only he seems to not support c++11, but auto is a *I dont understand what's going on so I slap auto and I am done with it* solution

Comment: @UmNyobe For me `auto` is "too lazy to write 30 char initialization / declaration".

Answer (score 0):

Your function Top() is declared const, and it's using the member variable vContainer.
Hence, you can't use "standard" iterator, but const iterator :

`typename vector<T>::const_iterator pos`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need the value but the position

```
void Top() const {
    T value = *max_element(vContainer.begin(), vContainer.end());
    . . .
}
```

Otherwise use `auto`

```
auto pos = max_element(vContainer.begin(), vContainer.end());
```